# Use search in fancybox

Tags: search

I'm trying to use FancyBox to open a lightbox-style popup with the `searchform.php`, when the user clicks on the search icon.

### **The setup:**

- in `header.php` I have a link element which will show only the search
  icon;
- in `script.js` I bind the click on the search icon to fancybox and I open the modal/lightbox `iframe` with the content of
  `searchform.php`;

**The problem:** the `iframe` doesn't load the WordPress environment so nothing is working. How can I use fancybox and still have access to the WP functions?

The next step will be to show the results of the search in the same `iframe` using AJAX.

**The code:**

```
// header.php
<a id="search-label" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/searchform.php"></a>

// searchform.php
<div class="search-container">
    <p>This is a test</p>
    <form action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" class="notv" id="search" name="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>  

// script.js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        $("#search-label").click(function () {
            $('.search-container').toggle();
            $('#search-label').fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none'
            })
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way:

1. create a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) that only includes the search form ([`get_search_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form))
2. create a page and assing the template
3. In the `href` attrib of the iframe, instead of put the url for `searchform.php` put the url of the page

Pretty easy, but you need a query to get the page. A more performant way is to use fancybox without iframe, but via ajax, e. g.:

```
<?php
$url = add_query_arg( array('action'=>'show_search_form'), admin_url('admin-ajax.php') );
?>
<a id="search-label" href="<?php echo $url; ?>"></a>
```

Then use [ajax API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to call `get_search_form()` inside the ajax action, e. g.:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_show_search_form', 'mytheme_show_search_form' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_show_search_form', 'mytheme_show_search_form' );

function mytheme_show_search_form() {
   get_search_form();
   exit();
}
```